# indicator-session user list 14.04 source code

Tags: 14.04, indicator, source-code

I am having problems with the length of my users list on the indicator-session on 14.04.2.

I was reading the source code and I saw a variable that don't understand.

In [service.c](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/indicator-session/trunk.14.04/view/head:/src/service.c#L1340) line 1340 I expected "max_users" where it says "max-users".

Could you help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you expect `max_users`?

Comment: Because when PROP_MAX_USERS enum is refered in the rest of the code appears "max_users" not "max-users". And, I think, the line 1340 is filling the enum.

Comment: Can you show such an instance where `max_users` is used to refer to that object?

Comment: I think that always that **p->max_users** are refered is refered a property of an object defined in class [line 1318](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/indicator-session/trunk.14.04/view/head:/src/service.c#L1318)

Comment: But that would be referring to the `max_users` field of the `_IndicatorSessionServicePrivate` struct (see [line 95](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/indicator-session/trunk.14.04/view/head:/src/service.c#L95)).